# JNI GetStringCritical does not get the good string

Tags: c++, c, java-native-interface

I use JNI to call native codes, and among the method parameters there is a string.

Therefore, I use GetStringCritical to get a pointer (char *) on the String.

```
Java_myjar_myclass___...(JNIEnv *env, jclass obj, ..., jstring Op, ...)
const char *op = (char*)env->GetStringCritical(Op, 0) ;
...
env->ReleaseStringCritical(Op, (jchar *)op) ;
```

But when I display *op, the length is correct, the first character is correct, but all the other characters are wrong. For exemple, "1234" becomes "1 �[]". How can I fix it?

Thank you for your help...

[EDIT] I followed the answers and I used a jchar*, not a char*. Then I can use it as a normal char* and it worked perfectly.

Comment: How are you displaying it?

Comment: AFAIK `GetStringCritical` gives you a pointer to an array of **unicode** characters. You seem to be assuming that you're getting plain chars.

Comment: Also why are you casting it to char*? The return type of GetStringCritical is `const jchar*` which is not the same as `char*` (or `const char*`).

Comment: Indeed, I made a mistake with the type conversion. How can I convert char to char* in C++?

Comment: Sorry typo... convert jchar to char*

Comment: Which character set and encoding (code page) do you need on the native side? If it is not Unicode/UTF-16 with the byte order that Java considers the platform default, it will have to be converted. Conversion is a bit easier on the Java side.

Comment: Your edit is incorrect. You can't use a `jchar *` as a normal `char *`. It points to Unicode-16 characters, not bytes. Voting to close as no longer reproducible.